# What does this Error mean : Undefined symbol: THREADVARLIST_STRINGS

Tags: arrays, pascal, undefined-symbol

I just started learning Free Pascal and I wrote this fairly basic program to practise arrays. I get two errors:

> Strings.lpr(32,1) Error: Undefined symbol: THREADVARLIST_STRINGS
>
> Strings.lpr(32,1) Error: Undefined symbol: STRINGS_STRPAS$PCHAR$$SHORTSTRING
>
> Strings.lpr(32,1) Fatal: There were 2 errors compiling module, stopping

The code is as follows:

```
program Strings;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes, SysUtils
  { you can add units after this };

{$R *.res}
var
  Marks : array [1..10] of Integer;
  index : Integer;
begin
  for index:= 0 to 10 do
  begin
    write('Enter mark of student ',index,': ');
    readln(marks[index]);
  end;

  for index := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    write('Student No. ',index,'   Marks: ',marks[index],'   ');
    if marks[index]>65 then writeln('PASS')
    else writeln('FAIL');
  end;

  writeln('Press any key to continue.');
  readln;
end. {line 32}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping the code would appear a little bit more colourful.

Comment: Apparantly you need to add the delphi tag for that.

Comment: True, @Marco, but tagging the question "delphi" suggests that it's actually about Delphi, which isn't the case here. Don't tag a question just for syntax highlighting. Use [the language-specification syntax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify) within the question instead. The Prettify highlighter still doesn't support a Pascal- or Delphi-specific highlighting rules, so the generic rules are all we get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't name your program strings. There is a precompiled unit with that name.

In general means that you create a mainprogram but don't link a proper RTL.

Possible causes:

- Version conflicts, (compiler<>RTL)
- mistakes made by manual linking (trying to access Pascal from C?)
- trying to use an embedded RTL that doesn't support certain language features.
- (**your case**) some naming conflict. But this is usually rare, and usually trapped by the compiler. Therefore, this experience might be worth filing as bug in the FPC bugtracker

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

program Strings;

to:

program testStrings;

corrects the error. Strings is a reserved word.

Also, you also have "Press Any Key" followed by readln. readln waits for a carriage return. Something like:

WriteLn('Press any key to continue.');
  repeat
  until KeyPressed;

is probably what you're looking for.